# How to auto-scroll to the last inserted value in list(Not Bottom).[[Note:List is Sorted]]

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css-animations

I'm trying to show the list of animes from an array.
I've sorted the list using 'oredrby' filter.
And I want to auto-scroll to the last inserted row in the list every time a new row is added.
Note that I don't want to auto-scroll to the bottom of the list.
Here's the

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fcv7hx4n/1/)

to demonstrate my problem.

```
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<title>Angular App</title>
<style>
    body{
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        div{
            width: 100%;
        }
        li{
            position: relative;
            animation: drop 0.7s;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        @keyframes drop{
            0%{
                height: 0;
                box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px;
            }
        }
        ul{
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            font-size: 40px;
            background-color: orange;
            list-style-type: none;
            scroll-behavior:  
           /* height: 75%; */

        }
        li:nth-child(odd){
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 40px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: white;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
        li:nth-child(even){
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 40px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: orange;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
        li:nth-child(odd) span{
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            right: 0px;
            width: 50px;
            height: inherit;
            background-color: #ff3333;
        }
        li:nth-child(even) span{
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            right: 0px;
            width: 50px;
            height: inherit;
            background-color: white;
        }
        li:hover{
            box-shadow: 0px -10px 30px;
            height: 80px;
            font-size: 60px;
        }
        form{
            /* height: 100px; */
            bottom:0;
            position: sticky;
            /* width:100%; */
            background-color: #081327;
            color: white;
            font-size: 40px;
            justify-content: center;
            align./-items:center; 
        }
        .error{
            display: flex;
            opacity: 1;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 40px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: black;
            color: #ff3333;
            z-index: 2;
            animation: show 0.7s;
        }
        .error span{

            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            right:0px;
            width: 50px;
            height: inherit;
            background-color: lightblue;
            color: #ff3333;
            transition:all 0.5s;
        }
        .error span:hover{
            background-color: red;
            color: black;
        }
        li span{
            position: absolute;
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
            right:0px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        li span:hover{
            background-color: red;
        }

        form input{
            border: 0;
            height: 100px;
            width:500px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size:40px; 
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Verdana;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 10px -10px 30px;
        }
        form button{
            border: 0;
            height: 100px;
            width:300px;
            font-size:40px;
            margin-bottom:20px; 
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #ff5413;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 10px -10px 30px;
        }

        @keyframes show{
           /* 20%{
                background-color: #1c1c1c;
            }
            40%{
                background-color: black;
            }
            60%{
                background-color: #1c1c1c;
            }
            80%{
                background-color: black;
            }
            100%{
                background-color: #1c1c1c;
            } */
            0%{

            transform-origin: center;
                height: 0px;
                width: 0px;
                font-size: 0px;
            }
            100%{
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 40px;
            transform-origin: center;
            transform: rotateX(360deg);
            }
        }
        #text{
            display: flex;
            position: absolute;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;  
            position: fixed;
        }
        #textinfo{
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 15px;
            font-size:40px; 
            border: solid black 5px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            min-width:400px;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: auto;
            background-color: white;
            animation:hello 0.5s;

        }


        @keyframes hello{
        0%{
            height:0px;
            font-size:0px;
        }
        100%{
            height:200px;
            font-size:40px;   
        }

        }
        #textinfo span{
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            animation: pop 1.4s;
            cursor: pointer;
            /* animation-delay: 0.9s; */
        }
    @keyframes pop{
    0%{

        transform:translateY(-1000px); 
    }
    50%{
    transform:translateY(0px);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100%{
    transform: rotateY(1turn);
    }
    }

    /* #description{
        height:200px;
        animation:flow 5s;
    } */
    /* @keyframes flow{
    0%{
        height:0px;
    }
    100%{
        height:200px;
    }
    } */

    </style>

<body ng-app="AngularApp" ng-controller="AngularAppCtrl">
    <div>
        <ul>
            Anime List
            <!-- <li ng-repeat="x in anime" ng-click="info(x.anime,x.hero)"> 
    {{x.anime}}<span ng-click="removeAnime($index)">&times;</span></li> -->
            <li ng-repeat="x in anime | orderBy" ng-click="info(x)">{{x}}
                <span ng-click="removeAnime(getIndex(x))">&times;</span></li>
        </ul>
        <form ng-submit="addAnime()" id="c">
            <div class="error" ng-show="existError">Anime Exists<span ng- click="removeErr()">&times;</span></div>
            <center>Enter New Anime<br>

                <input type="text" ng-model="newanime" ng- change="checkAnime()" placeholder="Enter Here!" style="color: black;"><button
                    type="submit">Add Anime</button>

            </center>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="text" ng-show="infoyes">
        <!-- <div id="textinfo">{{name}}<br>{{inform}}</br><span style="color:#ff3333" ng-click="removeInfo()">&times;</span></div> -->
        <div id="textinfo">{{name}}</br><span style="color:#ff3333" ng-click="removeInfo()">&times;</span></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('AngularApp', []);
    app.controller('AngularAppCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http, $anchorScroll) {
        //For fetching data from json
        /* $http.get('anime.json').then(function(response){
         $scope.anime = response.data.animes;
     });*/

        $scope.anime = ['Dragon Ball Z', 'One Punch Man', 'Naruto', 'One Piece', 'Yu Yu Hakusho', 'Tokyo Ghoul', 'Pokemon', 'Cowboy Bebop'];
        $scope.addAnime = function () {
            if (!$scope.newanime) { return; }
            if ($scope.anime.indexOf($scope.newanime) == -1) {
                /*var split = $scope.newanime.split(':');
                $scope.anime.push({'anime': split[0],'hero':split[1]});*/
                $scope.anime.push($scope.newanime);
                $scope.newanime = "";
                $scope.existError = false;
                $location.hash('c');
                $anchorScroll();
            }
            else {
                $scope.existError = true;
            }
        };
        $scope.removeErr = function () {
            $scope.existError = false;
        };
        $scope.removeAnime = function (x) {
            $scope.anime.splice(x, 1);
        };
        $scope.checkAnime = function () {
            if ($scope.anime.indexOf($scope.newanime) == -1) {
                $scope.existError = false;
            }
            else {
                $scope.existError = true;
            }
        };
        /*$scope.info = function (x,details) {
            $scope.infoyes = true;
            $scope.name = x;
            $scope.inform = details;

        };*/
        $scope.info = function (x) {
            $scope.infoyes = true;
            $scope.name = x;

        };
        $scope.removeInfo = function () {
            $scope.infoyes = false;
        };
        $scope.getIndex = function (x) {
            return $scope.anime.indexOf(x);
        }
    });
</script>

</html>



<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<title>Angular App</title>
<style>
    body{
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            overflow: auto;
        }
        div{
            width: 100%;
        }
        li{
            position: relative;
            animation: drop 0.7s;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        @keyframes drop{
            0%{
                height: 0;
                box-shadow: 0 -5px 10px;
            }
        }
        ul{
            text-align: center;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            font-size: 40px;
            background-color: orange;
            list-style-type: none;
            scroll-behavior:  
           /* height: 75%; */

        }
        li:nth-child(odd){
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 40px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: white;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
        li:nth-child(even){
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 40px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: orange;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
        li:nth-child(odd) span{
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            right: 0px;
            width: 50px;
            height: inherit;
            background-color: #ff3333;
        }
        li:nth-child(even) span{
            position: absolute;
            display: block;
            right: 0px;
            width: 50px;
            height: inherit;
            background-color: white;
        }
        li:hover{
            box-shadow: 0px -10px 30px;
            height: 80px;
            font-size: 60px;
        }
        form{
            /* height: 100px; */
            bottom:0;
            position: sticky;
            /* width:100%; */
            background-color: #081327;
            color: white;
            font-size: 40px;
            justify-content: center;
            align./-items:center; 
        }
        .error{
            display: flex;
            opacity: 1;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-size: 40px;
            height: 50px;
            background-color: black;
            color: #ff3333;
            z-index: 2;
            animation: show 0.7s;
        }
        .error span{

            position: absolute;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            cursor: pointer;
            right:0px;
            width: 50px;
            height: inherit;
            background-color: lightblue;
            color: #ff3333;
            transition:all 0.5s;
        }
        .error span:hover{
            background-color: red;
            color: black;
        }
        li span{
            position: absolute;
            transition: background-color 0.3s;
            right:0px;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        li span:hover{
            background-color: red;
        }

        form input{
            border: 0;
            height: 100px;
            width:500px;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size:40px; 
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Verdana;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 10px -10px 30px;
        }
        form button{
            border: 0;
            height: 100px;
            width:300px;
            font-size:40px;
            margin-bottom:20px; 
            font-family: Verdana;
            font-weight: bold;
            background-color: #ff5413;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 10px -10px 30px;
        }

        @keyframes show{
           /* 20%{
                background-color: #1c1c1c;
            }
            40%{
                background-color: black;
            }
            60%{
                background-color: #1c1c1c;
            }
            80%{
                background-color: black;
            }
            100%{
                background-color: #1c1c1c;
            } */
            0%{

            transform-origin: center;
                height: 0px;
                width: 0px;
                font-size: 0px;
            }
            100%{
            height: 50px;
            font-size: 40px;
            transform-origin: center;
            transform: rotateX(360deg);
            }
        }
        #text{
            display: flex;
            position: absolute;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;  
            position: fixed;
        }
        #textinfo{
            display: flex;
            position: relative;
            border-radius: 15px;
            font-size:40px; 
            border: solid black 5px;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            min-width:400px;
            overflow: hidden;
            width: auto;
            background-color: white;
            animation:hello 0.5s;

        }


        @keyframes hello{
        0%{
            height:0px;
            font-size:0px;
        }
        100%{
            height:200px;
            font-size:40px;   
        }

        }
        #textinfo span{
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 10px;
            animation: pop 1.4s;
            cursor: pointer;
            /* animation-delay: 0.9s; */
        }
    @keyframes pop{
    0%{

        transform:translateY(-1000px); 
    }
    50%{
    transform:translateY(0px);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100%{
    transform: rotateY(1turn);
    }
    }

    /* #description{
        height:200px;
        animation:flow 5s;
    } */
    /* @keyframes flow{
    0%{
        height:0px;
    }
    100%{
        height:200px;
    }
    } */

    </style>

<body ng-app="AngularApp" ng-controller="AngularAppCtrl">
    <div>
        <ul>
            Anime List
            <!-- <li ng-repeat="x in anime" ng-click="info(x.anime,x.hero)"> 
    {{x.anime}}<span ng-click="removeAnime($index)">&times;</span></li> -->
            <li ng-repeat="x in anime | orderBy" ng-click="info(x)">{{x}}
                <span ng-click="removeAnime(getIndex(x))">&times;</span></li>
        </ul>
        <form ng-submit="addAnime()" id="c">
            <div class="error" ng-show="existError">Anime Exists<span ng- click="removeErr()">&times;</span></div>
            <center>Enter New Anime<br>

                <input type="text" ng-model="newanime" ng- change="checkAnime()" placeholder="Enter Here!" style="color: black;"><button
                    type="submit">Add Anime</button>

            </center>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="text" ng-show="infoyes">
        <!-- <div id="textinfo">{{name}}<br>{{inform}}</br><span style="color:#ff3333" ng-click="removeInfo()">&times;</span></div> -->
        <div id="textinfo">{{name}}</br><span style="color:#ff3333" ng-click="removeInfo()">&times;</span></div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('AngularApp', []);
    app.controller('AngularAppCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http, $anchorScroll) {
        //For fetching data from json
        /* $http.get('anime.json').then(function(response){
         $scope.anime = response.data.animes;
     });*/

        $scope.anime = ['Dragon Ball Z', 'One Punch Man', 'Naruto', 'One Piece', 'Yu Yu Hakusho', 'Tokyo Ghoul', 'Pokemon', 'Cowboy Bebop'];
        $scope.addAnime = function () {
            if (!$scope.newanime) { return; }
            if ($scope.anime.indexOf($scope.newanime) == -1) {
                /*var split = $scope.newanime.split(':');
                $scope.anime.push({'anime': split[0],'hero':split[1]});*/
                $scope.anime.push($scope.newanime);
                $scope.newanime = "";
                $scope.existError = false;
                $location.hash('c');
                $anchorScroll();
            }
            else {
                $scope.existError = true;
            }
        };
        $scope.removeErr = function () {
            $scope.existError = false;
        };
        $scope.removeAnime = function (x) {
            $scope.anime.splice(x, 1);
        };
        $scope.checkAnime = function () {
            if ($scope.anime.indexOf($scope.newanime) == -1) {
                $scope.existError = false;
            }
            else {
                $scope.existError = true;
            }
        };
        /*$scope.info = function (x,details) {
            $scope.infoyes = true;
            $scope.name = x;
            $scope.inform = details;

        };*/
        $scope.info = function (x) {
            $scope.infoyes = true;
            $scope.name = x;

        };
        $scope.removeInfo = function () {
            $scope.infoyes = false;
        };
        $scope.getIndex = function (x) {
            return $scope.anime.indexOf(x);
        }
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by giving the id to the  list

```
<li ng-repeat="x in anime" id="list{{x}}">{{x}}</li>
```

And in addAnime() function I did this :

```
$location.hash('list'+$scope.newanime);
$anchorScroll();
$scope.newanime = "";
$scope.existError = false;
```

Here's the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0wurqf48/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using Javascript method [element.scrollIntoView();](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)

Something like this, maybe :

```
$scope.addAnime = function() {
    if (!$scope.newanime) {
    newanime.scrollIntoView();
      return;
    }
```